# Writing to Text File from Comma Delimited ArrayList

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, delimiter, printwriter

I have created a Song class that includes data members for a Song (Title, artist, album,length). I already have a .txt file that contains different songs which is stored into an array list. After the user finishes adding or deleting songs the program should write to the text file in the original format of the text file (comma separated).

My problem is that the program writes to the file without the commas and it is causing my program to crash when I re-run it by getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I have attempted to use nested for-loops and the printf function but have had no success. How can i write to the file with its original formatting and avoid crashing after i write to it and attempt to run it again?

**This is the format of the .txt File**
Rock Lobster,The B-52's,The B-52's,4:37
Walk Like An Egyptian,The Bangles,Different Light,3:24

**This is my Song Class with toString() method**

```
public class Song {
    //Declaring all data members.
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String album;
    private String length;
    private static int songCounter = 0;

    //Constructors for Song class.      
    public Song(String title, String artist, String album, String length){
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
        this.length = length;
        songCounter++;
    }
    //Get and Set methods 
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum(){
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album){
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getLength(){
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(String length){
        this.length = length;
    }

    public static int getSongCounter(){
        return songCounter;
    }
    public int compareArtist(Song o){
        return artist.compareTo(o.artist);
    }
    public int compareTitle(Song o){
        return title.compareTo(o.title);
    }
    //Overriding the toString() function.
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return title +","+artist+","+album+","+length;
    }
}
```

**This is my Main Class that reads from the file and contains a write method**

```
public class Library {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Song> songList = new ArrayList <Song> ();
    boolean repeat = true;

    try{
        Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("SongList.txt"));
        do{
            String line = read.nextLine();
            String [] tokens = line.split(",");
            songList.add(new Song(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3]));
        }while(read.hasNext());
        read.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }

    while ( repeat ){
        System.out.println("\nSelect a Function");
        System.out.println("1. Search Song");
        System.out.println("2. Add Song");
        System.out.println("3. Delete Song");
        System.out.println("4. Display Songs");
        System.out.println("5. Quit");

        switch (MenuInputCheck(1, 5)){

        case 1: searchSong(songList);
                break;
        case 2: addSong(songList);
                break;
        case 3: deleteSong(songList);
                break;
        case 4: displaySorted(songList);
                break;
        case 5: saveFile(songList);
                repeat = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static void saveFile(ArrayList <Song> songList){
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("SongList.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < songList.size();i++){
            writer.println(i);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presently the code is simply writing an `integer`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < songList.size();i++){
        writer.println(i);
 }
```

I suggest you create a method in `Song` which will write its fields sperated by commas

e.g.

```
public String writeMe () {
   StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer ();
   buf.append (name).append(",").append(artist).....;

   return buf.toString ();
```

}

and then in your loop call

```
writer.write (singList.get(i).writeMe ();
```

**Update**

Using you updated code you can get the output using

```
writer.println(song.toString());
```

Comment: I have edited my post with my Song class which includes a toString() method which separates by commas. would the call in my loop be similar to what you suggested?

Comment: Yes, writer.println(song.toString()); will be fine

Comment: You should consider using a CSV library to avoid common csv problems like embedded commas etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the value of `i` to the file??  You should be writing the song information.  In the absents of your `Song` class, I'm just making up fields and methods

If you're using Java 8 you can use the `StringJoiner` API...

```
public static void saveFile(ArrayList <Song> songList){
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("SongList.txt");
        for (Song song : songList){
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
            sj.add(song.getTitle());
            sj.add(song.getArtiest());
            sj.add(song.getAlbum());
            sj.add(song.getDuration());
            writer.println(sj.toString());
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will need to use something like a `String#format` or a `StringBuilder` to generate the output...

Now might be the time to introduce you to [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)...

**Updated**

So, based on your updated code, including the `Song` class, you should be able to do something as simple as...

```
public static void saveFile(ArrayList <Song> songList){
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("SongList.txt");
        for (Song song : songList){
            writer.println(song.toString());
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
}
```